# Python app running on Google app engine. How to make calls to Google Maps API?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-app-engine

I've managed to write a simple Python app using webapp2 to make requests to Google maps. When I run a local server, the requests are valid and everything works. I uploaded my contents to google's app engine and deployed it. Because of the change in environment, when I make a request, the IP address isn't white listed in my app engine configurations. Every time I add an address, the address changes.

**Long story short: python app running webapp2 makes calls to google maps locally but can't when deployed on app engine.**

Is there a specific module/library I should be using? I've looked everywhere but most solutions are deprecated or ask to use google.appengine.api which doesn't seem like it has what I need.

**EDIT**

Here's the code. The API call is made in mapRequests.getMapRequests()
when you run a local server and visit

http://localhost:8080/map/nearby/?radius=5000&latitudeUser=40.905451&longitudeUser=-74.838134&query=italian

**__init__.py**

```
import webapp2
import json
import cgi
import config
from mapRequests import *


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('**************************')


class mapHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,requestType,latitudeUser=None,longitudeUser=None,radius=None,query=None,referenceId=None):
    finder = mapRequests()
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'


    latitudeUser = cgi.escape(self.request.get('latitudeUser'))
    longitudeUser = cgi.escape(self.request.get('longitudeUser'))
    radius = cgi.escape(self.request.get('radius'))
    query = cgi.escape(self.request.get('query'))
    referenceId = cgi.escape(self.request.get('referenceId'))

    options = {
        'nearby' : finder.getMapRequest(latitudeUser,longitudeUser,radius,query),
        'location' : finder.getRestaurantQuery(referenceId)
    }

    self.response.write(options[requestType])

self.response.write(finder.getMapRequest(latitudeUser,longitudeUser,radius,query))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/map/(nearby|location)/',mapHandler)
], debug=True)
```

**mapRequests.py**

```
import json
import config
import urllib

class mapRequests():
    def __init__(self):
        self.error = {'status': 'FAIL'}
        return

    # Get nearby locations within specified radius
    def getMapRequest(self,latitudeUser,longitudeUser,radius,query):

    ....
        val = {
            'location': latitudeUser+','+longitudeUser,
            'radius': radius,
            'name': query,
            'type': 'food',
            'key': config.GOOGLE_PLACES_KEY
        }
        params = urllib.urlencode(val)
        resp = urllib.urlopen("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?%s" % params)
   return resp.read()

    # Get additional details about a particular location
    def getRestaurantQuery(self,referenceId):
        if not referenceId:
            self.error['referenceId'] = 'MISSING'
            return(json.dumps(self.error))
        return "Looking for a place\n"
```

This is what Google responds with when this is deployed and run on the app engine

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 107.178.195.162, with empty referer",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

When I say the IP changes, what I mean is when I add the IP seen here to the white list in my developer console, and then run the request again, it changes. 
Although the only similarity is the 107.178.(*).(*) subnet so I'll tinker with that as one person mentioned here. I'll get back to you on that.
Any other suggestions what it might be?

Comment: Please post your API call so we can see exactly what your are attempting to do. And what do you mean by "every time I add an address, the address changes"? Is an error reported or are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: i think he means that he's making a call to google's REST api and they use DNS load balancing to return a different IP. so there's not 1 single IP he can allow in the firewall to let his http traffic through. try pinging google.com multiple times, you'll notice the ip address isn't the same

Comment: Post updated. @JoshAllemon explained it better than I did.

Comment: i think you need to put your API key at the end of the request

Comment: I do that in mapRequests in the val dictionary as 'key'. Not going to show it for obvious reasons but it's located in another file called config.

Comment: gotcha. when you made the key did you put your local ip address as the only one allowed to make requests from that key?

Comment: I did, but that's when I was running a local server. As I mentioned, when I deployed and ran requests, it would give me a different IP each time and I would add that to the credentials. Because of the DNS load balancing it's going to give a bunch of IP's and I'm not going to add them all.

Comment: got it. you could either change the credential to use the whole subnet, or you could request a static ip under Networking/External IP addresses

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: Thanks: makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your API key to allow the entire subnet of google app engine servers to make requests to the Google APIs

add 107.178.0.0/16 to your credential in this case

Comment: Looking at this link I found Google Maps Coordinate API, which would be useful if it wasn't set for deprecation in Jan 2016.
I'm guessing Google has an alternative. Does anyone know where or what it is?

Comment: what about Google Maps Engine API. the one below it in the listing. never mind also deprecated. weird.

Comment: i signed up for the free trial of app engine to investigate this give me a sec

Comment: ok in the firewall rules part, can't you just add the subnet (i'm assuming that although the ip add changes, it's on one subnet) and allow it over tcp port 80? you'll need to to make outbound REST requests

Comment: I see what you described but I'm having a bit difficulty setting it up. Do you know how to set it as a range of IP's?

Otherwise, I'll keep playing with the network settings.

Comment: right, so now that you updated your post i don't think it's a firewall issue. it's an issue with your key. if you add 107.178.0.0/16 to your credential, it will add that whole subnet

Comment: THAT WAS IT! Thanks a bunch